# TextBlock: Binding of Text and StringFormat

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, textblock, string-formatting

Is it possible to bind `Text` and `StringFormat` too?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Price, StringFormat={Binding Path=DecimalPoints}}" />
```

*DecimalPoints* is constantly changing from `F0` to `F15`. Unfortunatelly the code above doesn't compile.

Comment: No, but you could probably do this using a converter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your best bet is definitely a converter.  Then your binding would look like this:

```
<TextBlock.Text>
   <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringFormatConverter }">
      <Binding Path="Price"/>
      <Binding Path="DecimalPoints"/>
   </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

Then a quick converter (you can certainly make it nicer, but this is the general idea).

```
    public class StringFormatConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
      #region IMultiValueConverter Members

      public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
          double number = (double)values[0];
          string format = "f" + ((int)values[1]).ToString();
          return number.ToString(format);
      }

      public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Works perfect, Thanks. What you mean "make it nicer"?

Comment: Well, for instance I am assuming that the values being passed are a double and an int. Also I am assuming that there are two values passed (instead of say - only one). You could make the method a little more foolproof by checking the arguments first.

Comment: @Liz, could you check for my question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134370/how-to-add-textblock-text-value-from-database-object-value

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned @Sheridan, in this case, `Binding` will not work. But you can create a class with static strings, and refer to them in XAML. The syntax is:

```
<x:Static Member="prefix : typeName . staticMemberName" .../>
```

Below is an example:

`XAML`

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat={x:Static Member=local:StringFormats.DateFormat}}" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat={x:Static Member=local:StringFormats.Time}}" />
</Grid>
```

`Code behind`

```
public class StringFormats 
{
    public static string DateFormat = "Date: {0:dddd}";

    public static string Time = "Time: {0:HH:mm}";
}
```

For more information, please see:

[x:Static Markup Extension on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

No you can't... the reason is because you can only bind to a `DependencyProperty` of a `DependencyObject` and the `StringFormat` property of the `Binding` class is just a `string`.