# Use resource with a parameter - WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, resources

I know that the use of regular resource is as follows:

```
Text="{x:Static prop:Resources.xxx}"
```

Is there a way to use resource with a **parameter** from a resource file in `XAML`?

Comment: Do you want to insert that parameter to the resource? Like string.Format(resourceFormat, parameter) ?

Comment: Please see my [`answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515482/textblock-binding-of-text-and-stringformat/18516105#18516105), may be help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as:

```
Text="{Binding Path=YourParameter, StringFormat='{x:Static prop:Resources.xxx}'}"
```